# iphone - How to tell which view is currently loaded in a tabBar app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Here is my scenario.  I have 3 out of 4 tab views that contain UIWebViews and UIImageViews.  I have the UIImageView on top of the webView to provide a loading image and I  remove the imageView when the delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad: is called.  This works just fine.

The problem I am running into is trying to handle the method webView:didFailLoadWithError: if/when my web content fails to load.  my webViews are different sizes for the 3 tabs so what I'm trying to do is if self.view equals one of my views (with webView) then add the subview (imageView) on the current view.

Basically I wan't to show an error image if the load fails in place of the loading image that is there for when the webView is loading.  I do not know how to tell which view is currently loaded.

I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: webView:didFailLoadWithError: passes you the id of the webview? - if you want to differentiate between the webViews, when you create them, set a tag `[myWebView setTag:1];` (a standard integer variable UIView's contain (webview is a subclass of uiview).. in your delegate method, do a switch method, with [webView tag] as your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current view controller with `-[UITabBarController selectedViewController]`.  Then use that view controller's `view` property.

Comment: Thanks so much for information Bongeh and Brian.  This is exactly what I've been searching for.